# AJAX, response of type callbackvar or callbackfunction

Tags: javascript, ajax

For a homework assignment, we are using a GET method to access to the web server where it returns types of JSON, XML, and script.  For script, it's defined as:

If script is specified, you must also either specify

```
a. callbackfunction
callme([{"id":"1383","name":"Sweet Deal","desc":"Great place for books","url":"http://amazon.com"}]);

b. callbackvar
items=[[{"id":"1383","name":"Sweet Deal","desc":"Great place for books","url":"http://amazon.com"}]];
```

So my sendRequest() method looks like:

```
function sendRequest()
{
    var transmission = document.getElementById("transmission").value;
    var url = "http://classwebsite.php" 
            + "?userid=crystal"
            + "&response=" + encodeValue(transmission);

        if (transmission == "script") {
        url += "&callbackfunction=formatData";
    }

    var callback = {success:handleResponse, 
            failure:handleFailure,
            timeout:5000
            };

    var transaction = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest("GET", url, callback, null);
}
```

But I'm not really sure what that means to use callbackvar or callbackfunction in the hw instructions.  Cause to me, the packet just looks like a JSON packet and I already have a method where I parse the JSON packet and format the data.

```
// What gets passed into this method is: YAHOO.lang.JSON.parse(response.responseText);
function formatData(message) {
    var str = "<table border=1 class='editable'>";
    for (var i = 0; i < message.length; i++) {
        str += "<tr>" + "<td>" + message[i].id + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + message[i].name + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + message[i].url + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + message[i].desc + "</td>" + 
                       "<td>" + "<a href='#' onclick='deleteRequest(this); return false' id='" + message[i].id + "'>delete</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    }
    str += "</table>";
    return str;
}
```

So in my handleResponse method from sendRequest, I thought I could just do this:

```
    else if (transmission == "script") {
    msg = formatData(response);
}
    var responseOutput = document.getElementById("responseOutput");
    responseOutput.innerHTML = msg;
```

Like I did with my JSON packet, but I don't see any output. Any thoughts?  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the response from the server is script content. So, inject the script tag with content of the responseText from the server on the page, and you're good to go.

When you do -

```
var callback = {success:handleResponse, 
        failure:handleFailure,
        timeout:5000
        };

var transaction = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest("GET", url, callback, null);
```

The callback that is invoked is handleResponse, and not formatData.

Comment: can you explain your answer more?  I changed the callback in my url to be handleResponse.  Then in my handleResponse method, I don't know how to parse the data that looks like "handleResponse([JSON packet])".  I tried using the same JSON parser in YUI, but I get an error.  Thanks.